# Script control client object loss of scope

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, scriptcontrol

I've got a script control that has a control embedded within it that exposes a server side property for a client side click event.  For example, embeddedControl.OnClientAppointmentClick.  So my question is how would I wire this event to my script control client object.  I've tried something like embeddedControl.OnClientAppointmentClick = "$find('myScriptControlClientID').onappointmentclick;" but on event firing the scope of the script control object is lost.  Any ideas on how to fix this? This problem has been bothering me for a long time and any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by adding a little helper method inline.

.OnClientAppointmentClick = "function(sender, eventArgs){$find('myscriptobject').Event(sender,args)};